# Linked Server permission DBA SQl server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

I want to assign such rights to a remote user so he can create a new linked server and can change only those linked servers that are created by him. How can I accomplish this? I have read about granting these permissions

GRANT alter any login TO [abc]

GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [abc]

GRANT ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER TO [abc]*

But with these permission, still this user can not create a new linked server through management studio. But he can create a new linked server with sp_addlinkedserver. How can I solve that? Moreover this user can alter any linked server that is not desired. So how can he only alter those linked server that are created by him.

I do not want to give him Sysadmin rights. This user is owning only few databases on servers. And other databases are from some other vendors.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit down the functions you need him to run; you could override the procedures and use [Execute As](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191296.aspx) to limit down the functions he can run. If you are limiting the specific linked servers to those created by him then in your version of sp_addlinkedserver add in a table that records what was created and then use that as a permissions check in your later procedures.